# How to access the data passed from the views in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, json

template.html

```
success: function (result, data) {
  alert(result["val"]);
  check = result[0]
  alert(check);
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'line',
      marginRight: 200,
      marginBottom: 75,
      marginLeft: 70,
      marginTop: 80,
      width: 900
    },
    title: {
      marginTop: 100,
      text: result[4]
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: result[1]
    },
  {%if result.0 == "power" %}
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 30
    },
  } 
  {%else %}
    yAxis: {
      min: 0.85,
      max: 1
    }, 
  {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
     list_values.append("power")
     list_values.append(m)
     list_values.append(p)
     list_values.append(q)
     list_values.append(msg)

     print list_values
     response.content = json.dumps(list_values, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
     return response
```

i am trying to plot the y axis based on the value i am sending from views. but it always goes to the else part. i am making a ajax request. How do i access the data i am passing from views in template where im using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing Javascript, Django views and Django templates.

In the javascript success callback, you can only use objects from your json response. (I simplify)

```
success : function(result, data) {
    // Dump objects
    console.log(result);
    console.log(data);
}
```

When your JSON response is correct, the javascript processing part has nothing to do with Django.